# Laravel 10 : Problem with store data type array to database with multiple request

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Helo Everyone I have problem with store data to database. I want to return the data the way I want it, so that it goes into the database.

But the data returned does not match what I expected. Here are the details of the code that I have

I build Application with Laravel 10 and This is my code

**file blade request :**

```
@foreach ($fields as $field)
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="form-group mb-3">
           <label class="form-label">{{ $field->name }}</label>
           <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="field_name[]" value="{{ $field->field_name }}" required>
           <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="field_icon[]" value="{{ $field->field_icon }}" required>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="field_value[]" required>
       </div>
      </div>
  @endforeach
```

**File Controller :**

```
$ad->save(); // This code before save to get ID

foreach($request->field_name as $field_name){
            $fields = [
                'advertisement_id' => $ad->id, //
                'field_name' => $field_name, 
                'field_icon' => $request->field_icon, 
                'field_value' => $request->field_value
            ];
    
        }
return $fields;
```

**But Return Data Like This :**

```
[
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Luas Tanah",
    "field_icon": [
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>"
    ],
    "field_value": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Luas Banguan",
    "field_icon": [
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>"
    ],
    "field_value": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Kamar Mandi",
    "field_icon": [
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>"
    ],
    "field_value": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Kamar Tidur",
    "field_icon": [
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>"
    ],
    "field_value": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ]
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Garasi",
    "field_icon": [
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
      "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>"
    ],
    "field_value": [
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6"
    ]
  }
]
```

**I Want to return Like this** :

```
[
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Luas Tanah",
    "field_icon": "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
    "field_value": "2"
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Luas Banguan",
    "field_icon": "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
    "field_value":"3"
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Kamar Mandi",
    "field_icon": "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
    "field_value":"4"
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Kamar Tidur",
    "field_icon": "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
    "field_value": "5"
  },
  {
    "advertisement_id": 72,
    "field_name": "Garasi",
    "field_icon": "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>",
    "field_value":"6"
  }
]
```

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part happens:

```
"field_icon": [
  "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
  "<i class=\"ti ti-arrows-maximize\"></i>",
  "<i class=\"ti ti-bath\"></i>",
  "<i class=\"ti ti-bed\"></i>",
  "<i class=\"ti ti-car-garage\"><i>"
],
"field_value": [
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6"
]
```

... because the *entire array* is being assigned in the foreach for those two fields, on *each* loop iteration.

Try with this controller handling instead:

```
foreach ($request->field_name as $key => $field_name) {
    $fields[] = [
        'advertisement_id' => $ad->id, //
        'field_name' => $field_name, 
        'field_icon' => $request->field_icon[$key], 
        'field_value' => $request->field_value[$key]
    ];
}
```

The `$key` will index the `field_icon` and `field_value` arrays with each loop iteration.

Updated to use `$key` based on suggested feedback.

Comment: why not `foreach ($request->field_name as $key => $field_name) {  .... $request->field_icon[$key] ... }` ?

Comment: That can definitely work too, better than the previous handling I had using `$i`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Aren't you overwriting `$fields` each iteration of the loop by using `$fields = ...` instead of `$fields[] = ...`?

Comment: @Daedalus ... good catch, just added, was not in the code copied from the OP's example.